# Best way to extract and classify medical codes from a document?

Tags: python, regex, data-science

I would like to parse medical documents and identify/classify words in them as various medical codes, such as HCPCS, ICD, CPT, APC, etc. I am thinking of the best way to do this; I have tried regular expressions, but they give me a lot of false positives (for example, HCPCS codes are generally either 5 numerical digits or 4 digits + 1 letter), but this picks up on things like 10000 mg, and other codes cannot be as simple as checking for 4 digits, as this picks up on years in many of the documents.

Certain codes like HCPCS are well formatted, but others, such as ICD, are not (M05.73, M05.732), as they can differ in terms of length, decimal places, and format (some documents would say M05.7x to M05.8x)

I have been thinking of a machine learning NLP approach as well, but I'm not sure what my features would be, aside from word length.

What would be some plausible approaches for this?

**Edit:**
Here is an example excerpt of a document:

> CODES NOTES: Previously, the unlisted HCPCS code C1889 was used to
>   represent this device. However, the appropriate HCPCS code which
>   describes the absorbable nasal implant device is C9749. The physician
>   work for the nasal implant placement would be billed with the unlisted
>   CPT code 30999 - Unlisted procedure, nose. Some providers may use CPT
>   30465 for this service, Repair of nasal vestibular stenosis (e.g.,
>   spreader grafting, lateral nasal wall reconstruction); however the
>   unlisted code is the appropriate code. Codes Number Description CPT
>   30999 Unlisted procedure, nose HCPCS C9749 Repair of nasal vestibular
>   lateral wall stenosis with implant(s) Date of Origin: November 2018
>   SUR209 | 8

Expected Output - Mapping of detected codes to possible code types:

C1889 (Possible code types: HCPCS)

C9749 (Possible code types: HCPCS)

30999 (Possible code types: HCPCS)

30465 (Possible code types: HCPCS)

Comment: Which type of data you have? is it text, or images?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to say without an actual dataset. I would suggest you add a sample to your question (as well as expected output). Also, are your medical codes always in an all uppercase format? Do you have a list of all of the medical codes somewhere?

Comment: The document is purely text. The codes may or may not be uppercase, and I do not have a list of all medical codes at the moment (I may try to find a complete list somewhere, but I am pretty sure certain code datasets like ICD must be paid for in order to obtain)

Comment: @ArthurLee does the text always begin with `CODES NOTES`?

Comment: Note that asking for software recommendations is off-topic here. See [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question).

Comment: The document all vary in terms of what they begin with. In response to @martineau, this is not a software recommendation question; this is an algorithm recommendation question.

Comment: @ArthurLee can you post your expected output for the given excerpt?

Comment: Arthur: Even if that's true, your question is so broad it's likely what the only responses you're going to get will be recommendations to use some third-party software.

Comment: @ArthurLee I'm wondering if you can give this regex a try ([test it here](https://regex101.com/r/wkHSpN/1)) against some other sample data you have to see if it correctly pulls the information: `\b(?!\d+\b|CODES|NOTES)([A-Z\d]{3,})\b\s+(?:code\s+)?([A-Z\d]{2,})\b`. Let me know if it fails on some data that you have and update your sample to include those breaking points. Regex isn't an ideal solution, but it is free.

Answer (score 0):

### cTAKES

[Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/) is an  NLP project for medical text processing which has pre-trained models for all kinds of content extraction and entity recognition specific for the medical domain. It's plausible that the types of codes you need are included in cTAKES either as a resource or as part of an entity tagging model.

Comment: This helps a lot. I will look into this, thank you very much!